# "respectively" referring to listed items in order

Tags: meaning

Is it correct to use "respectively" in this sentence? I want to express that the level of enounced is the "what" and the level of enunciation the "how" of the poem.

> Nünning (2009: 57) describes the level of the enounced and the level
>   of enunciation as the “what” and the “how” of the poem, respectively.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Respectively

(of two or more items) with each relating to something previously mentioned, in the same order as first mentioned.

For example :

> George and Kenneth were married in 1980 and 1985, respectively.

[Source : Respectively](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/respectively)

So your usage of the word "Respectively" is, undoubtedly, correct.